# Browser Caching

Tags: caching

I am trying to use the .htaccess file to "leverage browser caching" and get the users browser to cache the static assets.

Right now, I have my htaccess doing the index.php rewrite then this block of code.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

According to tools.pingdom my site still doesn't have any browser caching. 
Any ideas on this and how to get it to work?

I have tested this code on a static HTML site and it works for static asset caching.

Comment: Are you certain that mod_expires is installed (check phpinfo in CP)?  Is your Apache .conf file configured to allow you to add these rules in .htaccess -- it may be that you have to do it in the .conf itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went into the CP info and found it wasn't installed. Added it to the Apache server and did the restart and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my guess in the comments was correct I am adding it as an answer:

Check that mod_expires is installed in Apache (one way to quickly check in EE is to look at the phpinfo page in the control panel).